# How to use list tag in single line

Tags: html, css, list, formatting, inline

I want to use two list items with different css styles in the same line.    as:
**History**: Study of incidents happened in the past.
**Botony**: Study of plants.

(history and botony in bold and larger by 2px than the description.

But they are coming like this:
History:
Study of incidents happened in the past.
Botony:
Study of plants.

Below is the code i used:

```
<li id="subhead">History: </li><li id="describe"> Study of incidents happened in the past.</li></li><br>
<li id="subhead">Botany: </li><li id="describe">Study of plants.</li><br>


#subhead
{
float:left;
margin-left:30px;
list-style-image:none;
font-family:Times New Roman;
font-size:19px;
text-align:left;
font-weight:bold;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
display:inline;
}

#describe
{
float:left;
list-style-image:none;
list-style-type:none;
font-family:Times New Roman;
font-size:17px;
padding-left: 30px;
display: inline;
}
```

How can I get it done?

Please tell if I can do the same thing using p tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#subhead
{
font-size:17px;
display: block;
margin-left:30px;
list-style:none;
font-family:Times New Roman;
text-align:left;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
disply:inline;
}
#subhead span{font-weight:bold;font-size:19px;}
```

```html
<li id="subhead"><span>Physics: </span>Wilhelm Conrad Röntgen's for     the discovery of X-rays.</li>
<li id="subhead"><span>Chemistry: </span>  Jacobus Van't Hoff for chemical thermodynamics.</li>
```

Comment: Wow! thats awesome, a single line made it work. :) Thanks alot